# How can do insertion sorting, but to print the highest to the lowest GPA?

Tags: c, sorting, struct, insertion-sort, function-definition

I'm asked to write an code, to do insertion sorting to sort GPA from highest to lowest.
This is my code, and it's printing for me the same entered list :( there is no changes happens! so, the student with lowest gpa should be sorted to the end of the array. The output is only sort the GPA with out the ID. The point is here i need to sort Students by their GPA's and for sure their ID'S next to it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
   float GPA;
}STUDENT;

// method that sorts the array in descending order of GPA
void InsertionSortModified(STUDENT *StuAry,int N)
{
    int walk;
    float temp;
    bool located;

    for(int current =1; current <= N; current++){
        located=false;
        temp = StuAry[current].GPA;

        for(walk = current-1; walk>=0 && !located;)
        {
           if( temp > StuAry[walk].GPA)
           {
              StuAry[walk+1].GPA = StuAry[walk].GPA;
              walk --;
           }
            else
                located=true;
            StuAry[walk+1].GPA=temp;
        }
    }
}


void printArray(STUDENT *StuAry,int N)
{
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
       printf("%d %.2f\n",StuAry[i].ID,StuAry[i].GPA);
   printf("\n");
}

// testing main method
int main()
{
   STUDENT StuAry[]={{1,65.2},{2,75.3},{3,34.5},{4,99.9}};
   int N=4;
   printf("Before Sorting: \n");
   printArray(StuAry,N);
   InsertionSortModified(StuAry,N);
   printf("After Sorting: \n");
   printArray(StuAry,N);

   return 0;

}

//Now the problem is the output:
//Before sorting:
//1 56.20
//2 75.30
//3 34.50 
//4 99.90

//After sorting: //Notice her the integer(ID) it's not changing

//1 99.90
//2 75.30
//3 65.20
//4 34.50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Added this answer to keep this simple and easy to comprehend**
instead of stating from 0th index, I started with N-1 index, and compare with right most of elements, in short just opposite of generic insertion sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
   float GPA;

}STUDENT;

void InsertionSortModified(STUDENT *StuAry,int N) 
{ 
    int i, key, j; 
    STUDENT pnt;
    for (i = N-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        pnt = StuAry[i];
        key = StuAry[i].GPA; 
        j = i + 1; 

        while (j < N && StuAry[j].GPA > key) { 
            StuAry[j - 1] = StuAry[j]; 
            j = j + 1; 
        } 
        StuAry[j - 1] = pnt; 
    } 
} 

void printArray(STUDENT *StuAry,int N)
{
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
       printf("%d %.2f\n",StuAry[i].ID,StuAry[i].GPA);
   printf("\n");
}

// testing main method
int main()
{
   STUDENT StuAry[]={{1,65.2},{2,75.3},{3,34.5},{4,99.9}, {5, 12.21}, {6, 98}};
   int N=6;
   printf("Before Sorting: \n");
   printArray(StuAry,N);
   InsertionSortModified(StuAry,N);
   printf("After Sorting: \n");
   printArray(StuAry,N);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: I did it, but the output is a mess, can you please check it?

Comment: check this one, kept it simple, I traverse from right to left. compare element, if higher shift it to left and so on.

Answer (score 0):

walk >=0

- your temp should be a float

Comment: I did the changes, but still the output is not correct :C please check it again

Answer (score 0):

For starters as I understand you need to sort objects of the type STUDENT by the data member `GPA`. it means that during sorting you need to exchange whole objects if required instead of exchanging values of the data member `FPA`.

So these statements

```
temp = StuAry[current].GPA;
//...
StuAry[walk+1].GPA = StuAry[walk].GPA;
//...
StuAry[walk+1].GPA=temp;
```

do not make sense.

Within this for loop

```
    for(walk = current-1; walk>=0 && !located;)
    {
       if( temp > StuAry[walk].GPA)
       {
          StuAry[walk+1].GPA = StuAry[walk].GPA;
          walk --;
       }
        else
            located=true;
        StuAry[walk+1].GPA=temp;
    }
```

the statement

```
        StuAry[walk+1].GPA=temp;
```

is executed in each iteration of the loop because it is not a sub-statement of the else statement

```
        else
            located=true;

        StuAry[walk+1].GPA=temp;
```

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
   float GPA;
}STUDENT;

void insertion_sort( STUDENT a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        STUDENT current = a[i];

        size_t j = i;
        while ( j != 0 && a[j-1].GPA < current.GPA )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            --j;
        }

        if ( j != i ) a[j] = current;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    STUDENT a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i].ID  = ( int )i;
        a[i].GPA = ( rand() % N ) / ( float )N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    insertion_sort( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
(0, 0.4) (1, 0.4) (2, 0.1) (3, 0.7) (4, 0.3) (5, 0.7) (6, 0.9) (7, 0.1) (8, 0.2) (9, 0.0) 
(6, 0.9) (3, 0.7) (5, 0.7) (0, 0.4) (1, 0.4) (4, 0.3) (8, 0.2) (2, 0.1) (7, 0.1) (9, 0.0)
```

If you want that if two objects have the same GPA would be sorted in the ascending order of ID then the condition in the while statement can look as it is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
   float GPA;
}STUDENT;

void insertion_sort( STUDENT a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        STUDENT current = a[i];

        size_t j = i;
        while ( j != 0 && 
                ( a[j-1].GPA < current.GPA || 
                  ( !( current.GPA < a[j-1].GPA ) && current.ID < a[j-1].ID  ) ) )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            --j;
        }

        if ( j != i ) a[j] = current;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    STUDENT a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i].ID  = ( int )i;
        a[i].GPA = ( rand() % N ) / ( float )N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    insertion_sort( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
(0, 0.0) (1, 0.7) (2, 0.8) (3, 0.8) (4, 0.4) (5, 0.6) (6, 0.0) (7, 0.3) (8, 0.7) (9, 0.2) 
(2, 0.8) (3, 0.8) (1, 0.7) (8, 0.7) (5, 0.6) (4, 0.4) (7, 0.3) (9, 0.2) (0, 0.0) (6, 0.0)
```

As it is seen for example the first two records with the same GPA

`(2, 0.8)` and `(3, 0.8)`

are sorted in the ascending order by ID.

You could write a general sorting function that accepts a function that provides the required condition. For example

```
void insertion_sort( STUDENT a[], size_t n, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        STUDENT current = a[i];

        size_t j = i;
        while ( j != 0 && cmp( &a[j-1], &current ) > 0 )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            --j;
        }

        if ( j != i ) a[j] = current;
    }
}
```

So all you need is to supply a comparison function that will compares two elements of the array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
   float GPA;
}STUDENT;

int cmp_ascending( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const STUDENT *left  = a;
    const STUDENT *right = b;

    return ( right->GPA < left->GPA ) - ( left->GPA < right->GPA );
}

int cmp_descending( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const STUDENT *left  = a;
    const STUDENT *right = b;

    return ( left->GPA < right->GPA ) - ( right->GPA < left->GPA );
}

void insertion_sort( STUDENT a[], size_t n, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        STUDENT current = a[i];

        size_t j = i;
        while ( j != 0 && cmp( &a[j-1], &current ) > 0 )
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            --j;
        }

        if ( j != i ) a[j] = current;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    STUDENT a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i].ID  = ( int )i;
        a[i].GPA = ( rand() % N ) / ( float )N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    insertion_sort( a, N, cmp_ascending );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    insertion_sort( a, N, cmp_descending );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "(%d, %.1f) ", a[i].ID, a[i].GPA );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
(0, 0.5) (1, 0.9) (2, 0.6) (3, 0.3) (4, 0.2) (5, 0.6) (6, 0.1) (7, 0.3) (8, 0.0) (9, 0.3) 
(8, 0.0) (6, 0.1) (4, 0.2) (3, 0.3) (7, 0.3) (9, 0.3) (0, 0.5) (2, 0.6) (5, 0.6) (1, 0.9) 
(1, 0.9) (2, 0.6) (5, 0.6) (0, 0.5) (3, 0.3) (7, 0.3) (9, 0.3) (4, 0.2) (6, 0.1) (8, 0.0)
```

At first the array is sorted in the ascending order and then in the descending order.